# Add count of nested key as new key on array

Tags: javascript

I have the following example data from where I can count how many different `values` are in `details` but how could I have an array that would have it as key (`person_number`)?

*e.g. partial output*

```
const newData = [       
            {
              id: 222222,
              document_file_name: "4020653_FileName.pdf",
              document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
              document_type_label: "something",
              state: "accepted",
              person_number: 2,
              details: [
                {
                  id: 20656,
                  type: "Claimant",
                  name: "First Name Last Name",
                  first_name: "First Name",
                  last_name: "Last Name",
                  type_label: "claimant"
                },
                {
                  id: 20657,
                  type: "Fellow",
                  name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
                  first_name: "Fellow First Name",
                  last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
                  type_label: "fellow"
                }
              ]
            },
         (...)
```

```js
const data = [
        {
          id: 222222,
          document_file_name: "4020653_FileName.pdf",
          document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
          document_type_label: "something",
          state: "accepted",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20656,
              type: "Claimant",
              name: "First Name Last Name",
              first_name: "First Name",
              last_name: "Last Name",
              type_label: "claimant"
            },
            {
              id: 20657,
              type: "Fellow",
              name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
              first_name: "Fellow First Name",
              last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
              type_label: "fellow"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 1111111,
          document_file_name: "4020600_FileName.pdf",
          document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
          document_type_label: "something something",
          state: "rejected",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20656,
              type: "Claimant",
              name: "First Name Last Name",
              first_name: "First Name",
              last_name: "Last Name",
              type_label: "claimant"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 333333,
          document_file_name: "4020890_FileName.pdf",
          document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
          document_type_label: "something else",
          state: "rejected",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20657,
              type: "Fellow",
              name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
              first_name: "Fellow First Name",
              last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
              type_label: "fellow"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 444444,
          document_file_name: "4020672_FileName.pdf",
          document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",
          document_type_label: "something something else",
          state: "rejected",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20656,
              type: "Claimant",
              name: "First Name Last Name",
              first_name: "First Name",
              last_name: "Last Name",
              type_label: "claimant"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
    
      let name = [
        {
          id: "89",
          state: "accepted",
          document_type_label: "doc label",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20656,
              type: "Claimant",
              name: "First Name Last Name",
              first_name: "First Name",
              last_name: "Last Name",
              type_label: "claimant"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: "45",
          state: "accepted",
          document_type_label: "what else",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20656,
              type: "Claimant",
              name: "First Name Last Name",
              first_name: "First Name",
              last_name: "Last Name",
              type_label: "claimant"
            },
            {
              id: 20657,
              type: "Fellow",
              name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
              first_name: "Fellow First Name",
              last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
              type_label: "fellow"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: "47",
          state: "rejected",
          document_type_label: "another else",
          details: [
            {
              id: 20657,
              type: "Fellow",
              name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
              first_name: "Fellow First Name",
              last_name: "Fellow Last Name",
              type_label: "fellow"
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
      
      
      const count = data.map(x=>x.details.length)
      
      console.log("detailsCount: ", count);
      
      
      const arrWithCount = data.map(object => {
        return {...object, person_number: data.map(x=>x.details.length)};
      });

      console.log("arrWithCount: ", arrWithCount);
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. It would involve [iterating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) over the data array and adding a new property to each object based on the length of `details`.

Comment: @Andy I added to the code snippet what I wast trying but it's returning the all sequence of numbers instead of the related ones, which makes sense from my code. I just don't know how to do it differently and since it wasn't working correctly I didn't add it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the `length` of `object.details`, and set the `person_number` to that value.

```js
const data=[{id:222222,document_file_name:"4020653_FileName.pdf",document_updated_at:"2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",document_type_label:"something",state:"accepted",details:[{id:20656,type:"Claimant",name:"First Name Last Name",first_name:"First Name",last_name:"Last Name",type_label:"claimant"},{id:20657,type:"Fellow",name:"Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",first_name:"Fellow First Name",last_name:"Fellow Last Name",type_label:"fellow"}]},{id:1111111,document_file_name:"4020600_FileName.pdf",document_updated_at:"2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",document_type_label:"something something",state:"rejected",details:[{id:20656,type:"Claimant",name:"First Name Last Name",first_name:"First Name",last_name:"Last Name",type_label:"claimant"}]},{id:333333,document_file_name:"4020890_FileName.pdf",document_updated_at:"2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",document_type_label:"something else",state:"rejected",details:[{id:20657,type:"Fellow",name:"Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",first_name:"Fellow First Name",last_name:"Fellow Last Name",type_label:"fellow"}]},{id:444444,document_file_name:"4020672_FileName.pdf",document_updated_at:"2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z",document_type_label:"something something else",state:"rejected",details:[{id:20656,type:"Claimant",name:"First Name Last Name",first_name:"First Name",last_name:"Last Name",type_label:"claimant"}]}];let name=[{id:"89",state:"accepted",document_type_label:"doc label",details:[{id:20656,type:"Claimant",name:"First Name Last Name",first_name:"First Name",last_name:"Last Name",type_label:"claimant"}]},{id:"45",state:"accepted",document_type_label:"what else",details:[{id:20656,type:"Claimant",name:"First Name Last Name",first_name:"First Name",last_name:"Last Name",type_label:"claimant"},{id:20657,type:"Fellow",name:"Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",first_name:"Fellow First Name",last_name:"Fellow Last Name",type_label:"fellow"}]},{id:"47",state:"rejected",document_type_label:"another else",details:[{id:20657,type:"Fellow",name:"Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",first_name:"Fellow First Name",last_name:"Fellow Last Name",type_label:"fellow"}]}];

const arrWithCount = data.map(object => {
  return {...object, person_number: object.details.length};
});

console.log("arrWithCount: ", arrWithCount);
```